# Unable to import a module from the other file in ex47 Learning Python the Hard Way

Tags: python, automated-tests

I am doing ex47 in Learning Python the Hard W[enter link description here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex47.html)ay.

My problem here is that I am unable to import a module `from ex47.game.py import Room` from the other file in the following code:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game.py import Room

def test_room():
    gold = Room( "GoldRoom",
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, {})

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({'north': north, 'south':south})
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.") 
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

    start.add_paths({'west':west, 'down':down})
    west.add_paths({'east':start})
    down.add_paths({'up':start})

    assert_equal(start.go('west'),west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'),start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

And I have gotten the following error:

[image]

According to the website, this is a common problem and the author suggests to run `export PYTHONPATH=.` on Mac. But as you can see, I have ran it first before running the test also. Am I supposed to specify the pythonpath or this is due to some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this exercises right now and since I wanted a bit more explanation I've searched on the internet and found this post... hence my late response.. but I hope this helps if someone else encounter this problem.

He is not really clear about the structure of your Directory. So you should have a **ex47** *folder* with the `__init__.py` file and a **game.py** into the **ex47** *main folder*. Then in the *tests folder* you should have **ex47_tests.py** ...

So then then `from ex47.game import Room` works fine.

`from ex47`(is the package)`.game`(is the .module) `import Room`(is the class inside game.py)

```
ex47/
├── bin/
├── docs/
├── ex47/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── game.py
└── tests/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ex47_game.py
```

Answer (score 0):

`export PYTHONPATH=.` adds current directory to the list of paths that python will search when looking for a module.
That is, current directory at the time of the search, not the time you enter the line.

But, as you run your programe from `skeleton`, that will make python search for `ex47.game` in the `skeleton` directory.

How to fix it? Well, quick fix: `cd ../..` should bring you to the right place. But it's not very convenient. Better fix: change the `PYTHONPATH` variable to be the actual full path to the root of your project. That way, it won't depend on current directory.

Even better fix, you can make a small runner that sets the appropriate paths automatically before running anything. Assuming you put it at the root of your project, those lines will compute the full path to current script and add it to python search path:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
# do whatever here, for instance run your tests
```

For instance, for running nosetests, you could create a launcher script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import nose, os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
nose.main()
```

You put it at the root of your project, call it `nosetests.py` and run it instead of `nosetests`

*(As a sidenote, the preferred form of any kind of text on stackoverflow is actual text. This is because it allows other people who may have the same issue to find it through search engines - you can simply copy-paste your text, then use the brackets `{}` icon to make it look right).*

Comment: Thanks for your response! Option 2 works perfectly. However, I tried to implement option 3 also and put those lines in my game.py file and ex47_tests.py file, but it seemed like those are not the places to put it for it to run. Could you give me more information as where should I put those lines?

Comment: Fixed a missing component and added a sample launcher script.

Comment: @spectras I am still struggling with this issue, I have the required __init__.py(with double undersores) files in place and I have set the correct PYTHONPATH but still while running the `nosetests` it is unable to locate the correct module.

Comment: @user1> I suggest you open your own question. First, though it may sound similar, possibly it's not the same problem you have. Second, a new question will get much more attention from the community, increasing your chances to have a valuable answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know.... when you do import in python, you must not to include .py extension.

```
from ex47.game.py import Room
```

should have coded this instead:

```
from ex47.game import Room
```

where game.py was saved in the folder ex47. I hope this clarify your question.